# Flex depth property not working

Tags: apache-flex

Does the depth property apply only to Spark components? When I apply it to a non-spark container it doesn't change anything.

```
<mx:VBox height="100%" width="30" id="minimizeContainerLeft" clipContent="false">

</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used depth on a non Container and it worked. I used it with images. I set the depth of the element I wanted to 1 and the depth of the others to 0.

```
 container.getElementAt(oldValue).depth = 0;
 oldValue = val;
 container.getElementAt(val).depth =  1;
```

This way I bring the one image to the front and the other to the back.